# USB C/Thunderbolt, driver needed?

Tags: linux

I am thinking about buying a new notebook with USB type C Thunderbolt 3 only.
There are multiple adapters/docks that convert this Thunderbolt to VGA/HDMI/USB/Ethernet.

Is this hardware implemented or do I need specific drivers for that?
I think about a external monitor or Ethernet.

Or are these drivers already included in a modern Linux kernel?

I will run Debian Linux on it and I am not sure this adapters will work there yet.
All notebooks I can find have Windows installed out of the box.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Thunderbolt 3](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/USB4.html) is fully supported by Linux out of the box.

Debian might not work because it contains a relatively old kernel but as far as I know you can install a newer kernel, only it must be done manually.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Artem S. Tashkinov's answer,

You can download and build the kernel yourself! It's not that hard. [Here is how to do it.](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html)
Following that tutorial, as you have copied your current .config file, you just have to search for the thunderbolt option and enable it (if using 'make menuconfig', you can type '/' for searching for it).

For more specific instructions, the Gentoo's wiki has [just what you need](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/USB/Guide#USB_Type-C_and_Thunderbolt) to know.

Wish you success. If you have any problems, you can always look for more tutorials/forums or videos. The first time you build your own kernel may look a bit scary, but you'll see it's actually not!

Wish you luck! :)